# How to merge(push) array to array keep keys and values

Tags: php

I can't figure out this one when I tried `array_merge` it gave back array inside array. I just want to extend it from other array which is the same.

i have arrays like this, How can I extend them so there will be just more indexes with information make the array bigger.

```
["days"] => array(35) {
   [0] => object(stdClass) #4 (6) { 
    ["date"]= > string(10) "2014-06-29" 
    ["available"] => bool(false)
    ["type"] => string(11) "reservation" 
    ["subtype"] => NULL
    ["group_id"] => string(20) "reservation:17910584" 
    ["price"] => NULL
    }   
  [1] => object(stdClass) #5 (6) { 
    ["date"]= > string(10) "2014-06-30" 
    ["available"] => bool(false)
    ["type"] => string(11) "reservation" 
    ["subtype"] => NULL
    ["group_id"] => string(20) "reservation:17910584" 
    ["price"] => NULL
    }
}
```

And another array

```
["days"] => array(28) {
0-4....
[4] => object(stdClass) #8 (6) { 
["date"]= > string(10) "2014-07-03" 
["available"] => bool(false)
["type"] => string(11) "reservation" 
["subtype"] => NULL
["group_id"] => string(20) "reservation:19615924" 
["price"] => NULL
}

[5] => object(stdClass) #9 (6) { 
["date"]= > string(10) "2014-07-04" 
["available"] => bool(false)
["type"] => string(11) "reservation" ["subtype"] => NULL
["group_id"] => string(20)
"reservation:19615924" 
["price"] => NULL

}[6] => object(stdClass) #10 (6) { 
["date"]= > string(10) "2014-07-05" 
["available"] => bool(false)
["type"] => string(11) "reservation" 
["subtype"] => NULL
["group_id"] => string(20) "reservation:28128591" 
["price"] => NULL
}
6-28...
}
```

Comment: usage of `array_merge` would help

Comment: @insanebits yes you're right I was doing it wrong, It works now. I was trying to merge with empty array a third one and this way it doesnt work